# jQuery has/ contains words

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to achieve that, if "`clientpsseabq`" string is contained in variable `Var_words` then equal `true`, else `false`. I just have no idea what method or function do I need to use?

```
var Var_words = "https://www.go.me/outputsearchs/clientpsseabq"

if ( Var_words contains string "`clientpsseabq`"){
   return true;
}else{
   return false;
}
```

if someone could help me how can I complete this task?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the (native JavaScript) function [`String.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf):

```
if(Var_words.indexOf('clientpsseabq') !== -1) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

`.indexOf()` returns the index of the string. If the string is not found, it returns `-1`.

A smaller, cleaner solution would be to simply return the value of the conditional directly:

```
return (Var_words.indexOf('clientpsseabq') !== -1);
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, `indexof` should be `indexOf` otherwise, it doesnt work.

Comment: So it should, thanks. I must've mistyped it in my haste

Answer (score 3):

You can try this

```
if (Var_words.indexOf("clientpsseabq") >= 0)
```

or with care of case sensitivity

```
if (Var_words.toLowerCase().indexOf("clientpsseabq") >= 0)
{
   // your code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 if(Var_words.indexOf("clientpsseabq") >= 0))
 {

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

use a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) to test for the case

```
if(/clientpsseabq/.test(Var_words)){
    //given string exists
} else {
    //given string does not exists
}
```